# Error: cannot pickle '_global_parameters' object while performing state tomography with qiskit

Tags: qiskit, state-tomography

Qiskit version: 0.44.2
Operating system: 64-bit operating system, Windows 10 Pro

```python
import qiskit
from qiskit_experiments.framework import ParallelExperiment
from qiskit_experiments.library import StateTomography
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
qc=QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0,1)
qc.draw('mpl')
tomo_circuits = StateTomography(qc, (0,1))
from qiskit import IBMQ
IBMQ.load_account()
provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub='ibm-q', group='open', project='main')
# Select a backend (e.g., a quantum computer or a simulator)
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_qasm_simulator')
# Run the experiment
qstdata = tomo_circuits.run(backend, shots=8192).block_for_results() #<-- line 14
print(qstdata.analysis_results())
```

type error: cannot pickle `'_global_parameters'` object

The type error is coming while executing line 14. I have tried solutions like updating qiskit, changing backend and avoiding parallel computing. But nothing works. Please someone resolve the issue.